# Font-awesome icon not responding to ng-click

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a button as follows. The button is made of  <a> link, while the button text is a font-awesome icon of an eye.

```
<a class="action-button ng-scope" 
   ng-click="orderCtrl.showDetails(gridItem)">
      <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.action-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px 5px 4px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(172, 172, 172);
    width: 23px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 23px;
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37) inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 14px;
}
fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now what is strange is that the button only works if I click at the area outside of the font-awesome eye shape. If I click inside the eye, it does not trigger.

Comment: if your anchor tag is inside `orderCtrl` try with only `showDetails(gridItem)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include an anchor tag there because you are mixing two similar concepts.

Just do this instead.

```
<i class="fa fa-eye"  ng-click="showDetails(gridItem)"></i>
```